# what is the proper syntax for this SQL insert for PhpMyAdmin

Tags: phpmyadmin

Can someone please tell me where I can get a list of the proper code to insert for special characters like this **â€œ**?

Example of my code below:

```
`('907', 'rehab-blog', 'Therapists reactions to â€œDefinition of Measurable Improvement', 'therapists-8217-reactions-to-8220-definition-of-measurable-improvement-8221', 'dummy content here dummy end'),`
```

Comment: what special codes? it's just text... and that's definitely not an insert statement. it might be PART of an insert...

Comment: Where have you looked? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

These characters are only specials characters (in your case double quote : '“') which were badly encoded in UTF-8.

**You can find what you look for here** : http://www.i18nqa.com/debug/utf8-debug.html

If you whish to replace them, first check your UTF-8 encoding.